# View in ToolBar not getting property match_parent [Android]

Tags: android, view, android-menu, android-toolbar

In my android application, I am using ToolBar.

Code for ToolBar in xml is as follows :-

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_title_background" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/service_screen_title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/footer_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_title_footer" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I have also added menues in toolbar.
Now toolbar looks like this :-

[image]

As shown in image blue line which is mentioned as separate view in xml file.

But it not takes width completely of parent as shown in figure.
I want to show blue line below the menus also.

Comment: why separate view in xml file for just a blue line?

Answer (score 0):

can't you do like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/blue"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

---

`preview:`

[image]